# Object scope in TestCase class when using nose and python

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I'm using nose.

My current code is:

```
class A():
    def __init__():
        pass
    def do_somthing(self):
        do_it

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = A()
    def testSomthing:
        raise assert(self.a.do_something())
```

I don't want to create an instance of A class each test, I want to create it only once. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setUpClass`, see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-cases):

> A class method called before tests in an individual class run. `setUpClass` is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a `classmethod()`:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```